# Is there module to generate form and save into content type?

Tags: nodes, forms, webforms, entities

I find a module to create a form like Webform or Entityform and save this one directly into a node (specific content type or entity).

Comment: Doesn't Entityform support Rules to do such things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity form creates entity instances called "Entity form submissions". So the answer to your question is "Entityform module."

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your confirmation, but when i create a new Entityform with many submission. I don't understand where it's stored.

If i go to "/admin/structure/entity-type", there is no content in relation with "Entityform". And i want to access programmatically to this data in futur.

I have vanille drupal installation.

Do you have any ideas ?